# How to get Bluetooth devices in Nexus 6P and Moto M devices

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, nexus, android-bluetooth

In android studio if target version is 26, not getting bluetooth devices in nexus 6P (MarshMallow) and Moto M (nougat) other devices are getting(like pixel,moto g4, samsung).

If target version is 21, getting bluetooth devices in all devices.

Comment: Be more specific about what are you trying to do and what's the error.

Comment: Add BLUETOOTH, & LOCATION permissin and try again

Comment: I am not getting any error and bluetooth devices

Comment: added both permission that's why i am getting other devices @AkshayKatariya

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario like this one the problem is likely to be one of the below

1. Location and Bluetooth enabled?
2. Location/Bluetooth permission granted via runtime permissions

after the comment:
Also for API level 22 and above there is a different callback to get found BLE devices called `ScanCallback`

you must have this along with old `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` for older devices (API level 21 and below)

Comment: Both i have done, that's why i am getting bluetooth devices on other devices

Comment: I used like that  @ Neo

Comment: check below link @Neo
[link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/)